# [[object Object]] appear on textbox in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

[object Object] is automatically appeared as value in every textbox in my form. What went wrong? It appears after I inserted the attribute `name="searchr"` in `<form>` tag.

in search.htm:

> ```
> <form ng-submit="search()" ng-controller="formcontrol" name="searchr">
> <input type="search" placeholder="Search here" id="text_search" ng-model="searchr.text" name="text">
> ```

in controller.js:

```
.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, $http) { }
```

Comment: sounds to me like you may be binding objects to the textboxes instead of strings.  What does your html & controller code look like?

Comment: We can't debug code without seeing any line of it.

Comment: It's probably something to do with your `ng-model="searchr.text"`.  What is `searchr`?  I see it in the name attribute of your form, but do you have a js object by that name?

Comment: I also don't think that's the right controller that goes with that form.  Do you have a controller by the name `FormControl`, like the ng-controller attribute refers to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form name="searchr">
```

This creates an object of type FormController, and stores it into the scope under the name `searchr`.

```
<input name="text">
```

This creates an object of type NgModelController and stores it in the FormController's text attribute.

```
<input ng-model="searchr.text">
```

This tells angular that the model of the field (i.e. the text that must be displayed in the field) is `searchr.text`, but due to the above, `searchr.text`is the NgModelController object created by angular, which is part of the FormController object created by angular.

Don't use the same name for the form as the name you use to store the model of the form.

Comment: This answer pointed me into the right direction solving my problem where I accidentally used the same name for different input-tags in a very large form. When submitting/saving the object, one input field changed value to "[object Object]" but I could not log this value to the console anywhere. Instead I got the value I expected when debugging. I use Angular 8 in this case. Thank you.